# Matlab : how to change initial probability distribution of hidden markov model

Tags: matlab

How do I change initial probabilities distribution of hidden Markov model in MATLAB. I know by default, MATLAB begins the HMM algorithms at state 1.  To assign a different distribution of probabilities, the transmission and emission matrices are augmented to include the prior matrix. How can I do this?  I need answer with practical example. now assuming I have `Trans=[o.2, 0.8; 0.4, 0.6]` , `Emis=[0.6, 0.5, o.3; 0.4, 0.5, 0.7]` and `initial=[0.2 ,0.8]`

Comment: I've been using MATLAB for a while, and I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about. Please try to specify which part of MATLAB you're referring to. Simulink? Some toolbox? I might not be alone with my confusion.

Comment: I mean using hmmtrain function in matlab toolbox, how to change the default initial probability distribution